# Two subclasses mapped to the same table

Tags: inheritance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate in a project and have a problem I can't solve on my own:

```
class Cake {}
class CheeseCake : Cake {}
class VanillaCheeseCake : CheeseCake {}


class CakeMap :  Class<Cake> {
    Table("CAKE");
    Id(x => x.Id, "ID")
    .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    Map(x => x.CakeType);
}

class CheeseCakeMap :  Subclass<CakeMap> {
    Table("CHEESE_CAKE");
    KeyColumn("ID");
    Map(x => x.CheeseAmount);
}

class VanillaCheeseCakeMap :  Subclass<CheeseCakeMap> {

}
```

What I want is to have both `CheeseCake` and `VanillaCheeseCake` in the same table. `Cake.CakeType` could be used as a Discriminator. I also tried defining `VanillaCheeseCakeMap` as a ClassMap of `CakeMap` but then nhibernate doesn't find mapping for ID?

Comment: So where does `Cake` come into play? Is that in the same table as the other two or in a separate one?

Comment: `Cake` is just a base class, it has some common properties and is storred in a seperate "CAKE" table.

Comment: I'm actually not sure this is possible with FNH. If you map something using the `Subclass<>` mapping, you do not get a `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` method, which is what you need in the `CheeseCakeMap`.

Comment: I tried many things but could not get it to work with one table for both sublasses. If I create a seperate table for `VanillaCheeseCake`everything works as it should but I realy do not like this db inheritance thing (table per class), it makes db less readable. Thx Andrew.

Comment: So is using one table to store all three classes an option?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the schema to have one table for all cake types and discriminate on the caketype column but the following should work for what you suggested:

```
public enum CakeType
{
    Cake,
    CheeseCake,
    VanillaCheeseCake
}

public class Cake
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual CakeType Type { get; protected set; }
}
public class CheeseCake : Cake
{
    public virtual int CheeseAmount { get; set; }
}
public class VanillaCheeseCake : CheeseCake
{
}

public class CakeMap : ClassMap<Cake>
{
    public CakeMap()
    {
        Table("CAKE");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Type, "CakeType").ReadOnly();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("CakeType");
    }
}
public class CheeseCakeMap : SubclassMap<CheeseCake>
{
    public CheeseCakeMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(CakeType.CheeseCake.ToString());

        Join("CHEESE_CAKE", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("ID");
            join.Map(x => x.CheeseAmount);
        });
    }
}

public class VanillaCheeseCakeMap : SubclassMap<VanillaCheeseCake>
{
    public VanillaCheeseCakeMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(CakeType.VanillaCheeseCake.ToString());
    }
}
```